# Android App crashing due to setx and sety functions

Tags: android

I'm currently writing a small game for android in which a button changes position. After adding the setx and sety functions my app began crashing instantly upon opening.

Here's my code\

**JAVA**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Random rn = new Random();
    float ranx = rn.nextInt(19);
    float rany = rn.nextInt(10);
    Button red = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Red);
    red.setX(ranx);
    red.setY(rany);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.alex.strooper.MainActivity"
android:columnCount="11"
android:rowCount="18">

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Red"
    android:text="Red" />

</GridLayout>
```

Here's part of the error

```
09-13 21:49:23.108 28852-28852/? W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error

                                    [ 09-13 21:49:23.108 28852:28852 W/         ]
                                    Unable to open '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': No such file or directory
09-13 21:49:23.108 28852-28852/? W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': I/O Error
09-13 21:49:33.304 3807-3807/? W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f0a00ba (t=9 e=186) (error -75)
```

Comment: You're trying to find a `View` in your layout before you set the layout.

Comment: Thanks! How should I correct this?

Comment: Move the `Button` stuff to after the `setContentView()` call.

Comment: Thank you! this fixed the crashing

Comment: It clearly says `Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/oem-services.jar'`

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate method, Move the two last line of your code to the first of method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Random rn = new Random();
    float ranx = rn.nextInt(19);
    float rany = rn.nextInt(10);
    Button red = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Red);
    red.setX(ranx);
    red.setY(rany);

}
```